# Removing multiple entries in dictionary collection using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have this  class object:

```
    public class LoginInfo
    {
        public string EmailAddress;
        public string Alias;
        public string GuidLogOn;
    }
```

I declare this collection:

```
    public static Dictionary<string, LoginInfo> Users = new Dictionary<string, LoginInfo>();
```

I add an entry like this:

```
    LoginInfo loginInfo = new LoginInfo();
    loginInfo.Alias = "alias";         
    loginInfo.EmailAddress = "email";
    loginInfo.GuidLogOn = "guidLogOn";
    Users.Add("guidLogOn", loginInfo);
```

I then want to remove it like this:

```
Users.ToList().RemoveAll(x => x.Value.EmailAddress == "email" && x.Value.Alias == "alias");
```

But it still exists in the original collection.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First find all keys to be removed from the `Dictionary` and then use [`Dictionary.Remove(key)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kabs04ac(v=vs.110).aspx) method like:

```
var keysToBeRmoved =Users
    .Where(r => r.Value.EmailAddress == "email" && r.Value.Alias == "alias")
    .Select(r => r.Key)
    .ToList();

foreach (var key in keysToBeRmoved)
{
    Users.Remove(key);
}
```

The reason your code is not removing any values from the dictionary is, you are creating a copy of your `Users` dictionary and storing it a `List<KeyValuePair>` using `Users.ToList()`, Any modification in that will not affect the original dictionary.

Comment: Hi, yes I thought so and I already do the above.  What I was after was a one-liner if possible. Thanks

Comment: @AndrewSimpson If you want it on one line then remove all of the line breaks.  If you want it to be a single statement then you can simply remove the variable that is there only for the explicit purpose of separating the code into two statements for cleanliness purposes.

Comment: 'remove all line breaks' not really what I meant or after.

Comment: @AndrewSimpson, here is a one liner `Users = Users.Where(r => r.Value.EmailAddress != "email" && r.Value.Alias != "alias").ToDictionary(r => r.Key, r => r.Value);` **But don't do that**. First it is not removing items from the current dictionary, instead it is creating a new dictionary, second it doesn't really convey the intent of the code. May be the performance difference between this and code in answer would be negligible *(or worse than code in answer)*, but IMO it is all about conveying intent.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this.  I understand your points (everyone!) linq is new to me.  I will not do the one liner. Thanks for pointing out the reasons why not do this. I will accept the answer even though that is what i am doing already I concur with what you said.  thanks

Comment: @AndrewSimpson If you want to have a single statement, not a single line of text, then see the second half of my comment.